# Probability of finding $0$ successes in $4$ trials

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So here's the question:
In a factory, $4\%$ of the products produced in a week have flaws. We check all the products made in a week one after the other. What is the probability that we check more than $4$ products before finding one with a flaw?

Here's what I did:
I said that the event

A: finishing a flawed product counts as "success". $p(A)=0.04$

B: finding an ok product doesn't count as success. $p(B) = 0.96$

So I tried to solve it considering it as a Pascal distribution with $0$ success in $4$ products checked ($4$ consecutive products all are ok). But you can't have 0 successes in a Pascal distribution because then in the formula you get $(-1)!$ which is undefined. So how do you go about something like that?

Comment: Hint:  the condition is equivalent to "the first four products you test are non-defective."  Note: I'm assuming you count the defective one, so four good ones followed by a bad one is a success.  If you don't want to count that one, then you need the first five products you test to be non-defective.

Comment: Consider the associated problem: what is the probability of flipping a coin $4$ times and getting $4$ consecutive Heads?

Comment: You can choose either a binomial distribution ($0$ flawed products in $4$ tests) or a geometric distribution (more than $4$ tests to get $1$ flawed product).  I do not know precisely what a Pascal distribution is, but apparently it is a special case of a negative binomial distribution; so too is a geometric distribution.

Answer (score 2):

What we are looking for in this case is the probability that after checking 4 products we still have not found a faulty one, i.e. that four consecutive products are flawless. Hence, the probability of having to check more than 4 products is given by $p(more\: than \:4) = 0.96^4 \approx 0.849$.